# I want to make a method that returns the position the player is facing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, switch-statement, vector2

I made a simple script to check what position the player is facing and put that in my animator

1 = up

2 = right

3 = down

4 = left

```
private Vector2 velocity;
private Animator animator;
private int direction;
private void Awake() {
    animator = GetComponent<Animator>();

}
void Update(){
    velocity.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    velocity.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
    switch(velocity){
        case Vector2(0,1):
        direction = 1;
        break;
        case Vector2(1,0):
        direction = 2;
        break;
        case Vector2(0,-1):
        direction = 3;
        break;
        case Vector2(-1,0):
        direction = 4;
        break;
    }
    animator.SetFloat("Facing",direction);
```

then I get the error

Assets/Scripts/PlayerMovement.cs(21,25): error CS8129: No suitable 'Deconstruct' instance or extension method was found for type 'Vector2', with 2 out parameters and a void return type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your issue comes with how you are trying to use your switch statement as Vector(1,0) is attempting to call a function not actually reference the value you are looking a viable alternative is to use `when` like in the following example

```
                case Vector2 v when v.Equals(Vector2.up):
                    Debug.Log("Up");
                    break;
                case Vector2 v when v.Equals(Vector2.left):
                    Debug.Log("Left");
                    break;
                case Vector2 v when v.Equals(Vector2.back):
                    Debug.Log("Back");
                    break;
                case Vector2 v when v.Equals(Vector2.right):
                    Debug.Log("Right");
                    break;
```

I'm also using the shorthand `up`, `left`, `right` and `down` instead of defining the values manually

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `velocity` is of type `Vector2` you can't set the values of `x` and `y` as they are read-only properties.

Use this instead:

```
velocity = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Vectors are structs and you can't create them without using `new` e.g. `case new Vector2(0f, 1f):`. There are some ready made shortcuts for direction built in that you can use:

```
    if(velocity == Vector2.up)
    {
        print("direction = 1");
    } else if (velocity == Vector2.right)
    {
        print("direction = 2");
    } else if (velocity == Vector2.up)
    {
        print("direction = 3");
    } else if (velocity == Vector2.down)
    {
        print("direction = 4");
    } else if (velocity == Vector2.left)
    {
        print("direction = 1");
    }
```

Comment: it gives me the error
Assets/Scripts/PlayerMovement.cs(24,18): error CS0150: A constant value is expected

Comment: On which line of code?

Comment: the ones with the case Vector2....:

Comment: Yes you're right. My bad, you'll have to use IF statements instead, answer updated.